# Reload data from FlatList - React Native

Tags: react-native, reload, fetch-api, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that fetches data from my API, and I want to refresh it everytime my database gets updated. Can someone help me?

My code:

```
export default class Feed extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dataSource: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://192.168.200.100:3000/posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
render() {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView >
            <Header>
                <FeedModal></FeedModal>
            </Header>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={props => props.id}
                data={this.state.dataSource}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <FeedPosts title={`${item.title}`} photoDesc={`${item.description}`} postImg={`${item.photo}`} ></FeedPosts>}
            >
            </FlatList>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To update the values inside your app when changes happen on it from the backend you will need either a Real Time database or you will have to work with web sockets:

**Web Sockets:**
WebSocket is an internet communication protocol with a relevant interesting feature: it provides a full-duplex channel over a single TCP connection.

With WebSockets, a client and a server are able to talk to each other in real time, like they're involved in a telephone call: once connected, the client is able to receive data from the server, without any need to continuously refresh the web page. On the other hand the server will also be able to receive data in real time from the client inside the same connection. for react native check this article about [websockets](https://www.ably.io/topic/websockets-react-native) ,it should be handled from backend too.

**Realtime Database:**
Real-time database contains the data which is been processing in real-time. It uses the real-time processing techniques to handle the workloads.
for example firebase realtime-database.